# VIM fugitive plugin: how to run :Gwrite command with a -f parameter to force add a file from .gitignore?

Tags: vim

VIM fugitive plugin: how to run `:Gwrite` command with a -f parameter to force add a file from .gitignore?

Like `:Gwrite -f` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `:Git` command, which allows to run an arbitrary git command:

> :Git add -f %